# Passing parameters from one HTML page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've 2 pages; notes.html and symptoms.html. 
In symptoms.html, I've got some sort of rating system. Suppose that user selects 1 out of 0 to 2 scale, then it should be passed to calendar.html. I've at least 10 such ratings in symptoms page.

Code for symptoms page:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 23px;">Acne:</div>

<div class="starbox ghosting autoupdate" style="position: absolute; right: 16px; top: 3px;" id="acne"></div>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 42px; left: 23px;">Backaches:</div>

<div class="starbox ghosting autoupdate" style="position: absolute; right: 16px; top: 38px;" id="back"></div>
<script>
  function saveSymptoms() {
    var a = document.getElementById("acne");
    var b = document.getElementById("back");
    switch (classname = starbox ghosting autoupdate) {
      case 0:
        var one = low;
        break;
      case 1:
        var two = medium;
        break;
      case 2:
        var three = high;
        break;
    }
    var url = "notes.html?Agne=" + a,
      "back=" + b;
    window.location.href = url;
    console.log(url);
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function() {
      location.href = "notes.html";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Problem faced:
The parameters aren't getting passed to the url when clicked on save button.

Expected Result:
The output should be something like this:
`file:///C:/Users/AjayKumar/TizenWorkspace/PTracker/notes.html?acne=low;back=high`

My Result:
I'm getting this:
`file:///C:/Users/AjayKumar/TizenWorkspace/PTracker/notes.html?acne=;back=`

Comment: Firstly, is it a typo in question: `Agne=` ??? And what are you trying to pass? Because `var a = document.getElementById("acne")` returns a DOM node element

Answer (score 0):

`var a = document.getElementById("acne");`

will return a DOM object – in your case it will return a DIV. The DIV is a collection of a whole bunch of properties – it's like a box with a bunch of useful stuff in it. Right now you're assigning the box itself to the variables `a` and `b`; you want to find one of the items in the box (the text of the DIV, I think) and use that instead.

If you expect the text of the DIV to be the string "low", for example, you need to access the `innerText` property of the DIV. In other words, you'd want something like

`var url = "notes.html?Acne=" + a.innerText + "&back=" + b.innerText`

You can read about the properties of HTML elements, including the DIV, here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement

Your notes.html file is going to need to parse the query string, presumably with javascript; for that, you may want to check out [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter).

However:

I'd like to suggest that you're going about this with a non-standard, and thus more difficult, approach. It looks like you want the user to make a decision, e.g. whether a value is low, medium, or high. Typically, you'd do something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="notes.html">
<label>Acne Severity: 
  <select type=select>
    <option value="low">Low</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="high">High</option>
  </select>
</label>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

This way, you can use the HTML / Javascript FORM object; it's much easier to use for this sort of thing, as it's designed for user inputs, values, and submitting them to other pages.

You  might want to check out http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript for more info.

HTH!